# using a single number to represent multiple variables

Tags: c++, oop

so i have an issue that I need help finding a solution. The issue being that I am given various option codes for various car models and features:

- Car: Ford   : Option Code : 1
- Car: Citron : Option Code : 2
- Car: Nissan : Option Code : 4
- Car: Tesla  : Option Code : 8
- etc.

Along with a selection of colours

- Colour: Red : Option Code : 32
- Colour: Blue: Option Code : 64
- Colour: Black: Option Code: 128
- etc.

My Issue is that given various coding restrictions, I am given a function where the user can make a selection of what car they want in a specific colour but they can only enter a single option code

eg. 
If the user wanted a Ford (1) that was Red(32) they would enter 33.

So my question is What would be a good/ the best way of working out based on the option code sent to the function what options were selected, all options are increased by the power of 2. so from 33 i need to get back to 1 and 32.

Comment: So if they enter 239, they get a car that's a Ford, Citron(?), Nissan *and* a Tesla, in a red, blue and black colour scheme?  Anyway, you can test each bit using bitwise AND... so `options & 1 != 0` means it's a Ford, etc.

Comment: In other words: bad approach to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use bitmasking. For example, if the model code is 31 or less then you can say:

```
int car = code & 31;
```

To get the color you would just shift the code right 5 places:

```
int color = code >> 5;
```

You've picked powers of 2, but this is only useful if you want to combine values into the code. Whilst you do for car and color your solution also allows the code to contain a Ford and a Nissan, for example. If you don't want this then change the values so they're not powers of 2. You still need to mask them out, as shown above, but it will stop you getting mutually exclusive combinations, if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need masks to extract that information:

```
const unsigned modelMask = FordCode | CitronCode | NissanCode | TeslaCode ...;
const unsigned colorMask = RedCode | BlueCode ...;
```

now you can extract:

```
unsigned model = value & modelMask;
unsigned color = value & colorMask;
```

Comment: How do you create the value, e.g. for BlueFord?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov the same way you create masks in  your case `auto blueFord = BlueCode | FordCode;`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd usually use the binary "and" operator, like for example:

```
if (code & OPTION_CAR_FORD)
    cout << "Ford selected" << endl;
if (code & OPTION_CAR_CITROEN)
    cout << "Citroen selected" << endl;
// ...
if (code & OPTION_COLOR_RED)
    cout << "Red color selected" << endl;
// ...
```

Note that this does not prevent that somebody chose Ford+Citroen Red+Blue, that you must validate somehow (either here, or before, ideally right aftger the user input - e.g. to have selection boxes which will only allow one variant).